# Filter by column from joined table

Tags: c#, t-sql, simple.data

I've recently started using Simple.Data as my ORM. i've approached a problem with filtering by column from joined table.

My query looks like this:

```
var candidates = db.dbo.Candidates
            .FindAllBy(CommonOfferId: commonOfferId, CandidateId: null)
            .Select(
                db.dbo.Candidates.Id,
                db.dbo.Candidates.Email,
                db.dbo.CandidateProfiles.CandidateId
            ).LeftJoin(db.dbo.CandidateProfiles).On(db.dbo.Candidates.Id == db.dbo.CandidateProfiles.CandidateId);
```

I want to select entities which don't have ids in another table. This code is not working. I'm getting an exception, that `Candidates` doesn't have column `CandidateId`.

Is there any way to filter this query by value from joined table?

Answer (score 0):

It is almost correct:

```
dbo.Candidates
        .FindAllBy(CommonOfferId: commonOfferId, CandidateProfiles.CandidateId: null)
        .Select(
            db.dbo.Candidates.Id,
            db.dbo.Candidates.Email,
            db.dbo.CandidateProfiles.CandidateId
        ).LeftJoin(db.dbo.CandidateProfiles).On(db.dbo.Candidates.Id == db.dbo.CandidateProfiles.CandidateId);
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't at the computer. I cannot post my database model, but I can tell that CandidateProfiles has foreign key from Candidates and also it's CandidateId can be null.

Your example wasn't working because you cannot pass named parameters with dot. It just doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you have foreign keys defined in the database between `Candidates` and `CandidateProfiles` tables and it's a left join, I guess you could just write (not tested):

```
db.dbo.Candidates
   .FindAllBy(CommonOfferId: commonOfferId)
   .Where(db.dbo.Candidates.CandidateProfiles.CandidateId==null)
    .Select(
        db.dbo.Candidates.Id,
        db.dbo.Candidates.Email);
```

The main missing part in your code was the `.Candidates` in front of `.CandidateProfiles`. That's how you express left joins in Simple.Data and you can join multiple levels that way. It's very expressive and IMHO it's one of Simple.Data's best features.